# Filtering rows of numpy array based on whether row elements are in another array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have an array `group` which is Nx2:

```
array([[    1,     6],
       [    1,     0],
       [    2,     1],
       ...,
       [40196, 40197],
       [40196, 40198],
       [40196, 40199]], dtype=uint32)
```

and another array `selection` which is (M,):

```
array([3216, 3217, 3218, ..., 8039])
```

I want to create a new array containing all the rows of `group` where both elements are in `selection`. This is how I did it:

```
np.array([(i,j) for (i,j) in group if i in selection and j in selection])
```

This works, but I know there must be a more efficient way that takes advantage of some numpy function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.isin` to get a boolean array of the same shape as `group` that says whether an element is in `selection`. Then, to check whether both of the entries in rows are in `selection`, you can use `all` with `axis=1`, which will give a 1D boolean array that says which rows to keep. We finally index with it:

```
group[np.isin(group, selection).all(axis=1)]
```

---

Sample:

```
>>> group

array([[    1,     6],
       [    1,     0],
       [    2,     1],
       [40196, 40197],
       [40196, 40198],
       [40196, 40199]])

>>> selection

array([    1,     2,     3,     4,     5,     6, 40196, 40199])

>>> np.isin(group, selection)

array([[ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]])

>>> np.isin(group, selection).all(axis=1)

array([ True, False,  True, False, False,  True])

>>> group[np.isin(group, selection).all(axis=1)]

array([[    1,     6],
       [    2,     1],
       [40196, 40199]])
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I compared the results with timeit:
your solution `4.07 ms ± 197 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` vs. mine `263 ms ± 9.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
Much faster! :)